# Custom directive on datePicker not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Let's say i have custom direcitve that controls the count of numbers .

```
myApp.directive('myMaxlength', ['$compile', '$log', function($compile, $log) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            attrs.$set("ngTrim", "false");
            var maxlength = parseInt(attrs.myMaxlength, 10);
            ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                $log.info("In parser function value = [" + value + "].");
                if (value.length > maxlength)
                {
                    $log.info("The value [" + value + "] is too long!");
                    value = value.substr(0, maxlength);
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(value);
                    ctrl.$render();
                    $log.info("The value is now truncated as [" + value + "].");
                }
                return value;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

for example when i write `my-maxlength="10"` user can't write more than that .
the problem is when i add this directive to  [`angularUi Datepicker`](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) , i get an error :

`Error: value is null .link/<@http://andcweb.com/App/Directives/maxlength.js:10:1 NgModelController`

**HTML**

```
                    <input type="text" name="birth" class="form-control"
                           datepicker-popup-persian="{{format}}"
                           tabindex="7"
                           ng-model="requesterViewModel.BirthDate"
                           is-open="datePicker.opened"
                           datepicker-options="dateOptions"
                           date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)"
                           close-text="بسته"
                           min-date="minDate" max-date="dt" my-maxlength="6" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default iconBtn" ng-click="openPersian($event)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
                    </span>
```

Any idea? Many Thanks

Comment: First of all, why are you attempting to set maximum length of a date picker that already validates date format? In my opinion, this is just asking for a bad user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the error message carefully:

`Error: value is null .link/<@http://andcweb.com/App/Directives/maxlength.js:10:1 NgModelController`

This message provides the exact line number at which the error is occurring and a clear description of the error.

```
if (value.length > maxlength) { ... }
```

should be:

```
if (value && value.length > maxlength) { ... }
```

Otherwise, you may be attempting to read the `length` property of `null` when $viewValue is `null`.